# Suggested Routes - Google Directions API

Tags: google-maps

I want to get a list of directions between two locations. [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Routes) says that the results are placed in routes array.

I tried [directions using API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Hall%20Bazar,Amritsar&destination=Majitha%20Road,Amritsar&sensor=true) and got only a single direction, but when searched in Google Maps with the search text as "Hall Bazar, Amritsar to Majitha Road, Amritsar", I got three route suggestions.

Please correct me if I misunderstood Google Directions API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation, you need to ask for alternatives

&alternatives=true

Comment: Thank you good man. I'm surprised I missed reading it in the API doc.

Can you also help me in the following post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538932/all-directions-with-google-directions-api

Answer (score -1):

```
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives:true
};

put  provideRouteAlternatives:true
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little?

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.