# All Directions with google directions API

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way I can get all routes from my current location to "any other location"?

By any other location I mean that the map should show all valid directions to locations I **haven't** specified. The range (in terms of distance) of the directions may be, say, 1 mile from my current location.

The only parameter I want to provide is my current location and check which all directions I can travel over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Google Maps can't do this nativity.

Might commonly be known as "Time Travel" Maps

Can see a crude demo
http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html